# Query not ordering by name

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I’m trying to get a final result sorted by a-z order on `name` but getting `tag_id` ascending regardless of `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` changes… Any suggestion as to why?

```
SELECT
    r.tag_id tag_id,
    t.name name,
    COUNT(r.tag_id) tagPeak
FROM (
        SELECT pub_id
        FROM `wp_teachpress_relation`
        WHERE `tag_id` = 7
    ) pubs
    JOIN `wp_teachpress_relation` r ON pubs.pub_id = r.pub_id
    JOIN `wp_teachpress_tags` t ON t.tag_id = r.tag_id
WHERE
    r.tag_id NOT IN (7, 329, 326, 3, 4, 18, 19, 49, 69, 71, 80, 108, 120, 121,
        140, 141, 145, 148, 158, 160, 178, 183, 189, 190, 196, 199, 200, 201,
        206, 212, 218, 220, 221, 223, 230, 231, 233, 234, 236, 245, 257, 261,
        262, 287, 288, 306, 307, 323, 326, 329, 331, 332, 333, 334)
    AND t.name LIKE '%'
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Could you provide an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), please?

Comment: sorry would not know how... I can run suggestions on my DB if you have some ideas, thanks , jf

Comment: Just visit the sqlfiddle page, insert your database schema along with some sample data to the left textarea and copy the query from this page to the right one. Maybe [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) would help you. But be sure to provide a reasonably small (and still big enough) sample of your data. If you still could not manage to create a fiddle, ask a more specific question so that we can guide you.